# How to take a consecutive numbers into a bracket?

Tags: c

so I don't know how to make a number that is a consecutive number into a bracket. for example: 1 3 6 6 4 2 2 1 6. It should be: 1 3 (6 6) 4 (2 2) 1 6. Can someone help me? This is my code for now. Thank you so much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int lower = 1, upper = 6, count = 20, num;
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    printf("%d ", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to generate the numbers and store them into an array first. Or at least generate two numbers at a time before printing them so that you know whether an opening or closing bracket is needed. That is, you can't just print each number as it is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save all random value in an array and detect them if there same to the next one and different to the previous one to let the program know whether to print the bracket.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int lower = 1, upper = 6, count = 20, num;
    if (count == 0) return 0;  // if count = 0 then don't do anything
    srand(time(0));
    // if count = 1 just print the only random number
    if (count == 1) {
        printf("%d ", (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower);
        return 0;
    }
    int* arr = (int*) malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        arr[i] = num;
    }

    

    // Not to test i != 0 every loop
    if (arr[0] == arr[1]) {
        printf("(%d ", arr[0]);
    }else {
        printf("%d ", arr[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < count - 1; i++) {
        int a = arr[i - 1] == arr[i], b = arr[i] == arr[i + 1];
        if (!a && b) {
            printf("(%d ", arr[i]);
            continue;
        }else if (a && !b) {
            printf("%d) ", arr[i]);
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    // Not to test i != count every loop
    if (arr[count - 2] == arr[count - 1]) {
        printf("%d) ", arr[count - 1]);
    }else {
        printf("%d ", arr[count - 1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fixed the code that it didn't print the first element. But the last element works fine to me. It prints `)` perfectly.

Comment: Does not work for `1,1` https://godbolt.org/z/W4xdKjKEn

Comment: Ok, I think now I know what the problem is. I think it works fine now. The array element test may leak or something I don't know.

Comment: Fixed it, but I think yours is better and intuitive. I upvoted it.

Comment: It works fine for me, I have tried it and it came out with the exact answer that I want, Thank you to you guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
int print(FILE *fo, const int *arr, const size_t size)
{
    int insequence = 0, nchars = 0;
    if(fo && arr && size)
    {
        for(size_t curr = 0; curr < size - 1; curr++)
        {
            if(arr[curr] == arr[curr + 1])
            {
                if(!insequence)
                {
                    nchars += fprintf(fo, "(");
                    insequence = 1;
                }
                nchars += fprintf(fo, "%d ", arr[curr]);
            }
            else
            {
                if(insequence)
                {
                    nchars += fprintf(fo, "%d) ", arr[curr]);
                    insequence = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    nchars += fprintf(fo, "%d ", arr[curr]);
                }
            }
        }
        nchars += fprintf(fo, "%d%s", arr[size-1], insequence ? ")" : "");
    }
    return nchars;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 3, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0};

    print(stdout, arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/acGfj6oj4

And your case example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int lower = 1, upper = 6, num;
    size_t count = 20;
    int arr[count];
    
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        arr[i] = num;
    }

    print(stdout, arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nbe7ehPbn